# Ag-grid angular enable undo/redo after row insertion

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Please I am working on an ag-grid data-grid and I have implemented undo and redo, it is working fine.
But I have an issue which is I want to be able To undo/redo row insertion and row remove, so that when I add a new row I can undo it and redo it. Same for removed row.

Any suggestions please?

There is the content of my component.html file

```
 <div>
      <div style="float: left; width: 80%">
        <button mat-button class="btn btn-labeled mright" (click)="onAddRow()">
          <mat-icon class="icon-style-1" fontSet="material-icons-outlined"
            >add</mat-icon
          >
          <span class="span-style">Add</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-button class="btn btn-labeled mright" (click)="onDeleteRow()">
          <mat-icon class="icon-style-1" fontSet="material-icons-outlined"
            >delete</mat-icon
          >
          <span class="span-style">Delete</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-button class="btn btn-labeled mright" (click)="onBtnCopyClicked()">
          <mat-icon class="icon-style-1" fontSet="material-icons-outlined"
            >file_copy</mat-icon
          >
          <span class="span-style">Copy</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-button class="btn btn-labeled mright" (click)="onBtnPasteClicked()">
          <mat-icon class="icon-style-1" fontSet="material-icons-outlined"
            >content_paste</mat-icon
          >
          <span class="span-style">Paste</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-button id="undoBtn" class="btn btn-labeled mright" (click)="undo()">
          <mat-icon class="icon-style-1" fontSet="material-icons-outlined"
            >rotate_left</mat-icon
          >
        </button>
        <button mat-button id="redoBtn" class="btn btn-labeled mright" (click)="redo()">
          <mat-icon class="icon-style-1" fontSet="material-icons-outlined"
            >refresh</mat-icon
          >
        </button>
      </div>
      <div style="float: right; width: 10%">
        <button mat-button class="btn btn-labeled">
          <mat-icon class="icon-style-1" fontSet="material-icons-outlined"
            >file_download</mat-icon
          >
          <span class="span-style">Export to Excel</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="content-body" style="transform: translateY(2%)">
    <ag-grid-angular
      #myAgGrid
      class="ag-theme-alpine ag-center-cols-clipper"
      style="width: 100%;"
      domLayout='autoHeight'
      [rowData]="rowData"
      [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
      [columnDefs]="colDefs"
      [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
      [enableFillHandle]="true"
      [enableCellChangeFlash]="true"
      [undoRedoCellEditing]="true"
      [undoRedoCellEditingLimit]="10"
      [animateRows]="true"
      [rowSelection]="'multiple'"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
      (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered()"
      (cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
    >

    </ag-grid-angular>
  </div>
```

And there is the typescript file linked to it:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-management',
  templateUrl: './project-management.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-management.component.css']
})
export class ProjectManagementComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('myAgGrid') agGrid: AgGridAngular;

  /** Property that will help to manage the dialog referencing. */
  dialogRef;

  /**
   * Property that holds the value of theme saved inside the localStorage
   */
  themeClass = localStorage.getItem('classNameOfTheme');

  /**
   * Array contening the list of columns to be showed by the table.
   */
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'select',
    'employee',
    'project',
    'projectId',
    'workpackage',
    'task',
    'plannedEfforts',
    'accountedEfforts',
    'update',
    'delete',
  ];

  private gridApi!: GridApi<ToResize>;

  private gridColumnApi!: ColumnApi;

  rowData: ProjectMan[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      employee: 'John Doe',
      project: 'Falcon',
      pid: 'FALXxx',
      wp: 'Classic',
      level: 'In Approbation',
      task: 'Analysis',
      tpe: 48,
      tae: 12,
      w1: 6,
      w2: 6,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      employee: 'Morgan Freeman',
      project: 'ASIT',
      pid: 'ASITxxx',
      wp: 'Remote',
      level: 'Initiated',
      task: 'Analysis',
      tpe: 56,
      tae: 21,
      w1: 10,
      w2: 11,
    },
  ];

  colDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      headerName: 'Employee',
      field: 'employee',
      lockPinned: true,
      pinned: true,
    },
    { headerName: 'Project', field: 'project', lockPinned: true, pinned: true },
    { headerName: 'ProjectID', field: 'pid', lockPinned: true, pinned: true },
    { headerName: 'WorkPackage', field: 'wp', lockPinned: true, pinned: true },
    { headerName: 'Level', field: 'level', lockPinned: true, pinned: true },
    { headerName: 'Task', field: 'task', lockPinned: true, pinned: true },
    { headerName: 'Total Planned Efforts', field: 'tpe' },
    { headerName: 'Total Accounted Efforts', field: 'tae' },
    { headerName: 'Week 1', field: 'w1' },
    { headerName: 'Week 2', field: 'w2' },
  ];
  defaultColDef: ColDef = {
    sortable: true,
    filter: true,
    editable: true,
    resizable: true
  };

  public rowSelection: 'single' | 'multiple' = 'multiple';

  intervals: KeyValue[] = [
    {
      key: 1,
      value: 'Weeks',
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      value: 'Months',
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      value: 'Quarters',
    },
    {
      key: 4,
      value: 'Years',
    },
    {
      key: 5,
      value: 'Fiscal Years',
    },
  ];

  employeesArray: EmployeeInterface[] = [];

  DataConvToString: any[] = [];

  waiting = 'Waiting for closing';

  constructor(private paramService: ParamsProjectServiceService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const pop = this.paramService.launch();
    this.DataConvToString = this.dataReceivedToString();
    pop.afterClosed().subscribe(
      (result) => {
        if (result.confirm === 'yes') {
        console.log(`Logged value is: ${result.data.ressource}`);

          this.waiting = result.data.ressource;
          this.autoSizeAll(false);
        } else {
          console.log(`Logged value is: Closed`);
          this.waiting = 'closed';
          this.autoSizeAll(false);
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log('Error while calling params' + err);
      },
    );
  }

  autoSizeAll(skipHeader: boolean) {
    const allColumnIds: string[] = [];
    this.gridColumnApi.getColumns()!.forEach((column) => {
      allColumnIds.push(column.getId());
    });
    this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds, skipHeader);
  }

  onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent<ToResize>) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
  }

  onAddRow() {
    const selectedRows = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();

    if (!selectedRows || selectedRows.length === 0) {
      this.rowData.splice(0, 0, {
        id: this.rowData.length,
        employee: 'Name',
        project: 'Project',
        pid: '',
        wp: '',
        level: '',
        task: '',
        tpe: null,
        tae: null,
        w1: null,
        w2: null,
      });

    } else {
      this.rowData.splice(selectedRows[0].rowIndex + 1, 0, {
        id: this.rowData.length,
        employee: 'Name',
        project: 'Project',
        pid: '',
        wp: '',
        level: '',
        task: '',
        tpe: null,
        tae: null,
        w1: null,
        w2: null,
      });
    }
    this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
  }

  onDeleteRow() {
    const selectedRowNodes = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();
    const selectedIds = selectedRowNodes.map((rowNode) => {
      return rowNode.data.id;
    });

    this.rowData = this.rowData.filter(function (dataItem) {
      return selectedIds.indexOf(dataItem.id) < 0;
    });
    this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
  }

  onBtnCopyClicked() {
    this.gridApi.copySelectedRowsToClipboard();
  }

  async onBtnPasteClicked() {
    let tab: string[] = [];
    await navigator.clipboard.readText().then(
      (arr) => {
        console.log(`Arr is ${arr}`);
        tab = arr.split(/\s{2,8}/);
        tab.forEach((item, index) => {
          if (
            this.rowFound(item.replace(/\s+/g, ' '), this.DataConvToString) !==
            null
          ) {
            this.onElmtToPaste(
              this.rowFound(item.replace(/\s+/g, ' '), this.DataConvToString),
            );
          } else {
            console.log(`field ${index} not found`);
          }
        });
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(`An error occured : ${err}`);
      }
    );
  }

  onElmtToPaste(i: number): void {
    const selectedRows = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();
    console.log(`The index is ${i}`);
    console.log(`the value : ${this.rowData[i]}`);

    if (!selectedRows || selectedRows.length === 0) {
      this.rowData.splice(0, 0, this.rowData[i]);
    } else {
      this.rowData.splice(selectedRows[0].rowIndex, 0, this.rowData[i]);
    }
    this.DataConvToString = this.dataReceivedToString();
    this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
  }

  rowFound(s: string, tab: string[]): number {
    let r: number = null;
    tab.every((item, index) => {
      console.log(`conv ${s.includes(item)}`);
      if (s.includes(item)) {
        r = index;
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
    return r;
  }

  disable(id, disabled) {
    document.querySelector(id).disabled = disabled;
  }

  setValue(id, value) {
    document.querySelector(id).value = value;
  }

  onFirstDataRendered() {
    this.disable('#undoBtn', true);
    this.disable('#redoBtn', true);
  }

  onCellValueChanged(params) {
    const undoSize = params.api.getCurrentUndoSize();
    this.disable('#undoBtn', undoSize < 1);
    const redoSize = params.api.getCurrentRedoSize();
    this.disable('#redoBtn', redoSize < 1);
  }

  undo() {
    this.gridApi.undoCellEditing();
  }

  redo() {
    this.gridApi.redoCellEditing();
  }

  dataReceivedToString() {
    const converted = this.rowData.map(
      (item) =>
        item.employee +
        ' ' +
        item.project +
        ' ' +
        item.pid +
        ' ' +
        item.wp +
        ' ' +
        item.level +
        ' ' +
        item.task,
    );

    return converted;
  }
```

I use the methods **undo** and **redo** to undo/redo operations done and it is working fine. In the library it is said that undo/redo are applied only the followings events:

- Cell editing
- Copy / Paste
- File Handle

But I am looking for a way to make it works for row insertion and row delete, so that if I delete a row or I insert a new row I can be able to undo and redo these operations.

My view is looking like in the following link :
[ag-grid data view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUiYx.png)

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that don’t show what you’ve tried are generally more difficult to answer - people often skip right over them. So show your code for best results. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. To learn more about helping us help you, please start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Hello @DonBranson, Ok I get it. But the issue there is that my code is working properly I just want to enable a feature. Anyway, I will do what you suggested.

Comment: Hello @DonBranson, I updated it. Hope to get more help with these details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution for this, you have to implement your own undo logic for saving and loading row state.

There are many ways how this could be done.

The most straightforward approach(in my opinion) would be just to save row data at key points.

Here is Something to get you started.

```
export class AppComponent {
  
  // variables for custom undo
  undoIndex = 0;
  myUndoSaves = [];
  myUndoLimit = 5;
  
  onAddRow(e) {

    // just adding a row at the top of the grid
    this.rowData = [
      {
        make: (this.makeCount += 1) + ' Toyota',
        model: 'Celica',
        price: 35000,
      },
      ...this.rowData,
    ];
    // and saving rowData state
    this.saveRowDataSnapshot();
    
  }
  
  useMyUndo(action: 'undo' | 'redo') {
    let ifLeavingUndoSavesArray: boolean;
    
    switch (action) {
      case 'undo':
        ifLeavingUndoSavesArray =
        this.myUndoSaves[this.undoIndex + 1] == undefined;
        
        this.undoIndex = ifLeavingUndoSavesArray
        ? this.undoIndex
        : this.undoIndex + 1;
        break;
        case 'redo':
          ifLeavingUndoSavesArray = this.undoIndex - 1 < 0;
          this.undoIndex = ifLeavingUndoSavesArray ? 0 : this.undoIndex - 1;
          break;
        }
        
        // loading saved rowData state
        this.rowData = this.myUndoSaves[this.undoIndex];
      }
      
      saveRowDataSnapshot() {
        // manage how many undos you want
        if (this.myUndoLimit < this.myUndoSaves.length) {
          this.myUndoSaves.pop();
        }
        // adding new state
        this.myUndoSaves.unshift(this.rowData);
      }
      
      onGridReady(params) {
        // initial state save
        this.saveRowDataSnapshot()
      }
      
      
      columnDefs = [{ field: 'make' }, { field: 'model' }, { field: 'price' }];
      
      rowData = [
        { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
        { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
        { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 },
      ];
      private makeCount = 0;
    }
```

Here is a **working example on stackBlitz** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-undo-redo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you @MaraTataSan, effectively it is something like this. I will try to adjust it on my side and come back to you once done.

Comment: Hello @MaraTataSan, I'm back to the beginning again. Your solution provide me a way to undo/redo row insertion and deletion but now it disable the possibility to use undo/redo on cell edition, but I want both of them to work together. Have you another suggestion please ?